# How to transform List type in Power Query / M

Tags: powerquery, m

Is there a more direct way to transform the type of the elements in a list than via Table.TransformColumnTypes (which would add an additional clumsy transformation step)?

Using List.Transform (List, each _ as text) for example will return errors for number values. Is there a correct syntax for performing that transformation directly on a list (aim is to use Text.Combine in order to concatenate the list's values)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To convert a number to a text value, use Number.ToText. You can use something like this to use Text.Combine with your numeric list:

`= Text.Combine(List.Transform(List, each Number.ToText(_)), "separator")`

Comment: Thanks! Didn't get that we're acting on "cell"-level here. Actually for more general purpose (like sources that deliver lists where no specific format has been predefined) I'd use Text.From() then.